# PdfLaTeX: Undefined Control Sequence When Using Elsevier Template

Tags: pdftex, texlive-2020

I'm trying to compile a file using TeXLive 2020 using Overleaf. However, there occurs an `Undefined control sequence`, as shown below:

```
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
Learn more
l.48 \affiliation
                 [a]{organization={A}, % Address/affiliation
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.56 \affiliation
                 [b]{organization={A}, % Address/affiliation
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Strangly, using TeXLive 2021 has no problem. Unfortunately, the arXiv can only use TexLive 2020. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
%% ---------------------------------------- Class ---------------------------------------- %%

\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

%% Use the option review to obtain double line spacing
%% \documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the options 1p,twocolumn; 3p; 3p,twocolumn; 5p; or 5p,twocolumn
%% for a journal layout:
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

%% ---------------------------------------- Packages ---------------------------------------- %%

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption,setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.3](0,.45) -- (.25,0) -- (.8,.62) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Name}}

%% ---------------------------------------- Information ---------------------------------------- %%

\journal{E}

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{S}

\author[1]{FA}
\author[2]{SA}
\author[1]{TA\corref{cor1}}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\affiliation[a]{organization={A}, % Address/affiliation
            addressline={B},
            % city={},
            % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
            postcode={C},
            % state={},
            country={D}}
            
\affiliation[b]{organization={A}, % Address/affiliation
            addressline={B},
            % city={},
            % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
            postcode={C},
            % state={},
            country={D}}
            
\begin{abstract}
A
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword
K

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

%% \linenumbers

%% ---------------------------------------- Main Text ---------------------------------------- %%

\section{Intorduction}
\label{1}

\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}

\endinput

%% End of file `elsarticle-template-harv.tex'.
```

To easily produce it within 1 minute:

1. Download template from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle
2. Replace the content in `elsarticle-template-harv.tex` using above codes, then compile

Comment: Unrelated, but do remember that `hyperref` should (with a few exceptions) be the last `package` to be loaded (it needs to modify other packages), and as it is here `cleveref` should be loaded after `hyperref`

Comment: It would also be useful to know the exact error message you get from the compilation on Overleaf.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will update it now!

Comment: Remember that the `elsversion` on CTAN is newer than the one in Overleafs TeXLive 2020. AFAIR Overleaf takes TeXLive when it is released, and then it is frozen. Additionally, TeXLive is always released in Spring, and we can see that the `elsarticle` stuff was last updated on CTAN i the Autumn of 2020. So my guess is that `\affiliation` have have had a different name in earlier versions.

Comment: I just checked on my work PC. `\affiliation` exists `elsarticle` in fully updated TL20, but not in TL19.

Comment: Thus unlikely to be present in the version of `elsarticle` used in TL20 on Overleaf.

Comment: Yes, this is terrible, the ArXiv cannot select the version, maybe I need to prepare another one...

Comment: You just need to use the template that matches the older version of `elsarticle`

Comment: Yes, I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can solve this problem in a kind of circuitous way.

Just change

```
\affiliation[a]{organization={A}, % Address/affiliation
            addressline={B},
            % city={},
            % citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
            postcode={C},
            % state={},
            country={D}}
```

to

```
\address[a]{A, B, C, D}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Elsevier submission system has TL 2022. However, it reads a very old version of the `elsarticle.cls` ("elsarticle 2008/10/09, 1.0.2") from a different path instead of accessing it from `$path/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls`. It reads the old package from `$path/texmf-local/tex/latex/aries/elsarticle.cls`. This is the problem.

As a workaround, until they update the path, please upload the version of the class file that you are using to the submission folder along with your source files. The filetype should be selected as "Manuscript" instead of "LaTeX Source Files".

Answer (score 1):

Run the command: "latex elsarticle.ins" in the terminal to create the "elsarticle.cls" file. With this file the missing commands should be available.

If you have further problems consider to update your Texlive version to newest version.

Comment: This answer is a life-saver, for a combination of TeX Live 2020 (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21) and TeXShop Ver.5.27 . Thanks!